# how do a Git Rebase in Sourcetree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I want my local master branch to include the commit 'fixed js errors' and be rebased into origin/master.
[image]

I started the process like this:
[image]

Which leads me to this: 
[image: my Sourcetree]

But as you can see, I'm asked to pull before I push. And every time I pull I end up with a situation depicted in the first image. What am I doing wrong?! Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original structure would not support rebasing. Let's say you had a commit to your local `master` and someone else had committed (and pushed) another change to `origin/master`. In this scenario, you could rebase your commit on top of the other commits.

Your scenario has a commit from a completely different branch. You would either need to merge your other branch into `master`, or you could cherry pick that one commit and apply to the `master` branch.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I did the cherry pick method you recommended because it was just one commit, but in the future I will merge other local branches into master.